# Site reported as blacklisted by Norton Safe Web, with no reason given. How to resolve?

Tags: security, malware, blacklist

A WordPress website that I monitor using ManageWP (by running a daily security report) has been reported as blacklisted by Norton.

I visited the Norton website to investigate the reason (creating an account and verifying ownership of the site as part of the process) and was presented with the message as shown in the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of Norton Safe Web blacklist report]

Since it says "The threat categorization is not complete", it seems there's no specific information I can use to fix the site just yet.

**Can anyone advise on how long it might take before details are added to the report, or whether there's any particular things that are worth checking in the meantime?**

Comment: At this point in time, the site has been blacklisted for over 30 hours.

Comment: Norton design team be trippin

Comment: Also check on https://mxtoolbox.com/.  The website will check against many more other blacklist sites.  Perhaps you can figure out where the problem lies.  Have you checked your site just manually for any weird codes?

Answer (score 1):

The message is rather cryptic. Are you sure that's the real Norton and not some scammer wanting to scam you? I mean, why was the message issued if there are "0" threats on the site? Anyway, I bet your best option would be to scan for malware on the site in Cpanel. You may also wish to reach out to your host for help. Also, go into Google Search Console and check if there are any security issues on the site.

But my best bet is that there is nothing wrong with the site and the message itself is the scam.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's the real Norton. Thanks for your answer! I'll see if Search Console shows anything up.

Comment: FWIW, I have seen the same thing on a site that did have some malware, but was cleaned 3 months earlier.  I have been doing computers for about 40 years and I have learned to _never_ trust Norton security.